# android rotation handling

Tags: android, testing

Is `onDestroy()` guaranteed to be called when I rotate the screen?

I heard that one can define `onConfigurationChanged()` to change this default behavior. What would usually be written in that method? And what are the other ways to change the default behavior of rotation?

Answer (score 1):

Is `onDestroy()` guaranteed to be called when I rotate the screen?

Yes

[onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) will be called for any configuration change you want to handle yourself (you declare those configurations under configChanges in your manifest). I think the best would be to avoid that altogether.

You can disable rotation in the manifest by setting Orientation for your activity such as 'portrait' or 'landsacpe'

Normally if the orientation can change you will want to save and then restore some of your data using [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and then restoring the data back in onCreate